# remove a single quote in a string with pySpark using regex

Tags: regex, apache-spark, pyspark

I need to remove a single quote in a string. The column name is **Keywords**. I have an array hidden in a string. So I need to use Regex within Spark Dataframe to remove a single quote from the beginning of the string and at the end. The string looks like this:

```
Keywords=
'
  [
      "shade perennials"," shade loving perennials"," perennial plants"," perennials"," perennial flowers"," perennial plants for shade"," full shade perennials"
  ]
'
```

I have tried the following:

```
remove_single_quote = udf(lambda x: x.replace(u"'",""))
cleaned_df = spark_df.withColumn('Keywords', remove_single_quote('Keywords'))
```

But the single quote is still there, I have also tried `(u"\'","")`

Answer (score 4):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace

new_df = data.withColumn('Keywords', regexp_replace('Keywords', "\'", ""))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try regexp_replace

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace,col
    cleaned_df = spark_df.withColumn('Keywords', regexp_replace('Keywords',"\'",""))
```

OR

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
    cleaned_df = spark_df.withColumn('Keywords', f.regexp_replace('Keywords',"\'",""))
```

I have not tested It but should work

```
import ast

    cleaned_df = spark_df.withColumn('Keywords',ast.literal_eval('Keywords'))
```

Please [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list)

Comment: I ran both methods, but the single quote is still appearing  in my rows :/

Comment: As an alternative you can convert this string into list and then access the first 0th element

Comment: Infact you dont even need to convert into list you can directly access 0th element from string

Comment: Updated answer please chk